# FluentValidation how to create common part

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have an abstract (it's no matter) class:

```
public abstract class CarrierAbstractFormAPI
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Fein { get; set; }
    public string McNumber { get; set; }
    public string DotNumber { get; set; }

    public AddressCreateAPI Address { get; set; }
}
```

and AddressCreateAPI class:

```
public class AddressCreateAPI
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string ZipPostalCode { get; set; }
    public int StateProvinceId { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactPhone { get; set; }
    public string ContactFaxNumber { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
}
```

My Validator:

```
public abstract class CarrierAbstractFluentValidation<T> : AbstractValidator<T> where T : CarrierAbstractFormAPI
{
    public CarrierAbstractFluentValidation()
    {
        RuleFor(d => d.Name)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Name is required");

        RuleFor(d => d.Fein)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Fein is required");

        RuleFor(d => d.McNumber)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("McNumber is required");

        RuleFor(d => d.DotNumber)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("DotNumber is required");

        RuleFor(d => d.Address.Street)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Address Street is required");

        RuleFor(d => d.Address.City)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Address City is required");

        RuleFor(d => d.Address.StateProvinceId)
            .InclusiveBetween(0, int.MaxValue).WithMessage("Address State is required");

    }
}
```

It works fine.
But I have some additional classes, which can have

```
public AddressCreateAPI Address { get; set; }
```

property. 
I want to move a part:

```
        RuleFor(d => d.Address.Street)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Address Street is required");

        RuleFor(d => d.Address.City)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Address City is required");

        RuleFor(d => d.Address.StateProvinceId)
            .InclusiveBetween(0, int.MaxValue).WithMessage("Address State is required");
```

to common class and the apply it in every my fluent validator, which has property Address. How to do it?

Comment: If `Address` property is inherited from some common base class/interface you can create a base validator class that validates said property (narrowing template parameters to classes that implement said class/interface) and derive validators from that. If not - you can create base class that uses reflection to inspect passed generic parameter to whether or not it exposes `Address` property and apply appropriate validation rules if applicable.

Comment: no inheritance. Address is only example, can be other different common parameters, which need to be validated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Come to think about it all you need to do is to reuse a validator class.

```
class AddressCreateAPIValidator : AbstractValidator<AddressCreateAPI>
{
    public AddressCreateAPIValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(d => d.Street)
        .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Address Street is required");

        RuleFor(d => d.City)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Address City is required");

        RuleFor(d => d.StateProvinceId)
            .InclusiveBetween(0, int.MaxValue).WithMessage("Address State is required");
    }
}

class SomeClass
{
    public AddressCreateAPI Prop { get; set; }
}

class SomeClassValidator : AbstractValidator<SomeClass>
{
    public SomeClassValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(d => d.Prop).SetValidator(new AddressCreateAPIValidator());
    }
}
```

Notice how `AddressCreateAPIValidator` extracts common logic for validating `AddressCreateAPI` classes and is then reused for properties by using a call to `SetValidator`.

You can mix and match this with reflection-based approach from the other answer if you want to create a generic validator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following extension method that inspects the passed type via reflection and applies the specified validation rules:

```
public static bool Apply<T, TProperty>(this AbstractValidator<T> validator, string propertyName, Action<IRuleBuilderInitial<T, TProperty>> rule)
{
    var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);

    if (property == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{typeof(T).Name} does not expose property {propertyName}!");
        return false;
    }

    if (!typeof(TProperty).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Property {typeof(T).Name}.{propertyName} is of type {property.PropertyType.Name} which is not (derived from) {typeof(TProperty).Name}!");
        return false;
    }

    rule(validator.RuleFor(t => (TProperty)property.GetValue(t)));

    return true;
}
```

Example usage:

```
class a
{
    public string Prop { get; set; }
}

class b
{
    public DateTime Prop { get; set; }
}

class c
{
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

class Validator<T> : AbstractValidator<T>
{
    public Validator()
    {
        this.Apply<T, string>("Prop", r => r.NotEmpty().WithMessage("Prop is required"));
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(new Validator<a>().Validate(new a { Prop = "AAA" }));
Console.WriteLine(new Validator<a>().Validate(new a()));
Console.WriteLine(new Validator<b>().Validate(new b { Prop = DateTime.Now }));
Console.WriteLine(new Validator<c>().Validate(new c { Prop2 = "AAA" }));
Console.WriteLine(new Validator<c>().Validate(new c { Prop2 = "AAA" }));
```